# How Would I Iterate Over Count Fields and Total Them And Output Via String Interpolation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2's *ngFor and string interpolation to iterate over sub-fields and print them to the screen, along with the "count" for each sub-field. This is what the data looks like on the DB:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "status": "gold",
      "sub": "Category A"
    },
    "count": 19
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "status": "gold",
      "sub": "Category B"
    },
    "count": 27
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "status": "gold",
      "sub": "Category C"
    },
    "count": 24
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "status": "",
      "sub": "Category D"
    },
    "count": 11
  }
]
```

And this is how I am printing them to the screen in my view:

```
<ul class="action-list">
    <li *ngFor="let record of records" class="action">{{record._id.sub}}<span class="action-counts">{{record.count}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

And in my component I am calling a counts service this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.streamGoldCountsService.getCount()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

So far everything's working as expected.

My question is, how would I total those various sub-counts, and then print the total to the screen? We don't have the total of the sub-categories in our database, so I will need to do some math in my component. But I'm not sure how best to do this. Thoughts?

Comment: Why not just do the counting when you get the records back? Calculated once, nice and neat.

Comment: What would that look like approximately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through the records something along the lines of:

```
  totalCounts(data) {
    let total = 0;

    data.forEach((d) => {
      total += parseInt(d.count, 10);
    });

    return total;
  }
```

Here is a plunker example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/IylOI2JMwCpGyhmgJCUq/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!